# right shift conversion in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

This code triggers a warning with `-Werror=conversion` (GCC 10.1), and I don't understand why:

```
std::uint16_t i = 24, j = 12, k = 13;
std::uint16_t x = (i >> j) & k;
```

> error: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘uint16_t’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’}
> may change value [-Werror=conversion]

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), the return type of the right shift operator is simply the type of its LHS, which should be `std::uint16_t`. Adding two `std::uint16_t` should produce another `std::uint16_t`, so why am I getting a warning?

Note that everything works just fine if I do this:

```
std::uint16_t i = 24, j = 12, k = 13;
std::uint16_t x = (i >> j);
std::uint16_t y = x & k;
```

Comment: Arithmetic on integers smaller than `int` causes them to be promoted to `int` before the arithmetic. It's called integral promotion.

Comment: you are looking at the wrong table. The table on the page you link is "prototye examples for class T", it is signatures of typical custom implementations. `uint16_t` is not a class type. Read on: "Conversions If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion"

Comment: Oh right I had forgotten about that. But then, why doesn't the second code sample give me any warning? x and y are narrowing conversions.